# How to use react-dnd-scrollzone in our application.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-redux, react-dnd

I am very new to reactJS. I have to add `autoscrolling` feature with drag and drop component. that's why i am using react-dnd-scrollzone.
While using example from  "https://github.com/azuqua/react-dnd-scrollzone", I am having following errors :

> 'Scrollzone' is not defined 
>   'ScrollingComponent' is assigned a value but never used

Please if anyone can help me with this and tell me how to use this in my code.
The snippet below is showing few lines of my code where i used scrollzone.

```js
const DndComponent = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(ScheduleBoard);
const ScrollingComponent = withScrolling(ScheduleBoard);
const vStrength = createVerticalStrength(500);
const hStrength = createHorizontalStrength(300);

const zone = (
  <Scrollzone verticalStrength={vStrength} horizontalStrength={hStrength}/>

 
);
  
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    clearErrors,
    getToday,
    setPage,
    getDepartments,
    getTaskList,
    getUnscheduledTasks,
    unscheduleTask,
    putUnscheduleTask,
    rescheduleTask,
    putRescheduleTask,
    mergeTasks,
    putMergeTasks,
    unmergeTasks,
    putUnmergeTasks,
    resizeWindow,
    startLoader,
    startDeptLoader,
    unscheduledFilter,
    createReservationNote,
  }
)(DndComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the define a ScrollZone as said in react-dnd-scrollzone documentation. Here is the basic example.

```
import withScrolling, { createVerticalStrength, createHorizontalStrength } from 'react-dnd-scrollzone';

const Scrollzone = withScrolling('ul');
const vStrength = createVerticalStrength(500);
const hStrength = createHorizontalStrength(300);

// zone will scroll when the cursor drags within
// 500px of the top/bottom and 300px of the left/right
const zone = (
  <Scrollzone verticalStrength={vStrength} horizontalStrength={hStrength}>

  </Scrollzone>
);
```